# About $\pi(x)<li(x)-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}\log(\log(\log(x)))$

Tags: prime-numbers

Today I found that in 1914, Littlewood proved that

**(1)** there are arbitrarily large values of $x$ for which

$$\pi(x)<li(x)-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}\log(\log(\log(x)))$$

- First: Is this true?
- Second: Is **(1)** equivalent to:

**(2)** There are infinitely many $x$ such that

$$\pi(x)<li(x)-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)}\log(\log(\log(x)))$$?

Thanks!

Comment: No, (2) does not necessarily imply (1). The infinitely many $x$ could lie in a bounded interval.

Comment: But does "arbitrarily large $x$" mean that there's not a finite number of $x$ such that inequality holds?

Comment: The point is that 1 implies 2, but the converse is not true.

Comment: What's the difference between "arbitrarily large values" and "infinitely many values"? thanks

Comment: $1/n$ takes infinitely many values in $[0,1]$, but not arbitrarily large values (for $n\in \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Ok, last question: are there infinitely arbitrarily large values of $x$? is this true?

Comment: This is a bit tautological, and one would not say it like this, but it seems not wrong either.

Comment: oh :P so what's a better statement for what I said before? or just saying "arbitrarily large values" implies that they are infinite? if yes, now I get your first comment and why that looks a bit tautological.

Comment: Yes, arbitrarily large always implies (implicitly) that there are infinitely many. For each bound $M$ you get one $x_M$ greater than $M$ but then you get another $x_M'$ grreater than $x_M$ and so on; showing that in fact you have infinitely many larger than $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning lower and upper bounds of $\pi(x)-li(x)$ Saouter and Demichel have shown in $2010$ that
$$
\frac{-0.2x}{\log^3 x}-\frac{12x}{\log^4 x}-C_1-C_2\le \pi(x)-li(x)\le \frac{0.51x}{\log^3 x}-C_1 \quad \forall \; x\ge 355991,
$$
with
$$
C_1=li(2)-\frac{2}{\log 2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\log 2}+\frac{2}{\log^2 2}\right),
$$

$$
C_2=\int_2^{e^8}\frac{48}{\log^5 t}dt-\frac{24}{\log^4 2}.
$$

The best result for the difference is obtained if we believe in RH:

**Theorem (Schoenfeld 1976):** If the Riemann hypothesis holds, then for all $x\ge 2657$ we have
$$
|\pi(x)-li(x)|\le \frac{1}{8\pi}\sqrt{x}\log x.
$$

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand the link bewteen the question an the answer at all. The question concerns a result showing that  $\pi(x)  < li(x) - g(x)$ with positive $g(x)$ of a certain size. This is in some sense exactly the opposite of the results recalled in the answer that can be used to show $\pi(x) > li(x) - g_1(x)$ yet never *less than*.

Comment: You're right, I mean he answered to a question that I was going to ask..

Comment: @quid: I added the lower bound on $\pi(x)-li(x)$, too. I think these are the relevant estimates concerning $\pi(x)-li(x)$, right ?

Comment: They are certainly relevant estiamates but different from the ones asked about. Your estimates give an **upper** bound on $|\pi(x) - li(x)|$ whiel the one in the question give a **lower** bound (with additional information in which direction). The result in the question is around sign-changes and oscillations of the remainder (not about bounding its size from *above*). // To make this more clear: if $\pi(x)$ were $0$ it would still fulfill the Littlewood estimate

Comment: I see. The reference of the original paper of Hardy and Littelwood answers the question of course. I was assuming that the other estimates were also interesting in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The result in the question is first proved by J.E. Littlewood in Comptes Rendus de l'Academie des Sciences, June 1914.

The result is expressed as:

$$\pi(x)-Li(x)<-K\frac{\sqrt{x}\log\log\log x}{\log x} $$

$$\pi(x)-Li(x)>K\frac{\sqrt{x}\log\log\log x}{\log x}. $$

He concludes that the inequality $\pi(x)<Li(x),$ "presumed by many authors for empirical reasons, cannot obtain for any value of $x$ however large."

He does not specify K.

His conclusion may be interpreted to mean that for any value of $x,$ however large, for which one sense of the inequality holds, one can find a larger $x$ for which the other sense holds, and so on.

Ingham's later proof is somewhat easier (The Distribution of Prime Numbers, Ch. V).

Answer (score 1):

The result you quote from Littlewood is stated and proved in [that paper of Hardy  and Littlewood](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02422942) (see theorem 5.8 and below, page 194).